# Unable to connect to docker container to container

Tags: docker

I have created couple of docker ubuntu images in my Debian host.

```
1. app01 - sudo docker run --name app01  -P -id ubuntu-control-container-bkup
2. control - sudo docker run --name control  -p 22:22 -id ubuntu-control-container-bkup
```

Now, from control container im trying to ssh connect to app01 container but I get connection refused error.

```
root@5ffdec48995f:/# ssh 172.17.0.2
ssh: connect to host 172.17.0.2 port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: Check the IP of app01 to confirm that you has the correct one: `docker inspect app01`. Then check whether it has the 22 port open: `docker exec app01 ss -ltn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ssh isn't installed or enabled by default. if you really need it, you'll need to install it via your Dockerfile.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/

but you might want to consider these things:

https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/

Comment: Thanks.Im lil bit confused after reading the article as im from traditional background..We generally use a ansible control machine to ssh to different boxes and install multiple packages..How do I install different packages(tons of linux/python packages) if I can't ssh..

Comment: each different type of target machine would be a separate Dockerfile and image to build... php app? Dockerfile and image. rails app? Dockerfile and image. nginx? Dockerfile and image. etc etc. instead of deploying configuration to a server, you build the configuration into the image and deploy images - all configuration already done and handled. no more configuration drift, no more dynamic configuration of servers for a specific app. just deploy the image and run containers from it.

Comment: that's not to say ansible isn't still useful. lots of good docs and aricles on using them together, out there... but if you're replacing ansible deployed apps with docker, then this is the general approach you would take.